# BarChart does not fit on chart area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

By using the code below, the X axis maximum value is only `85000` and that hides the partly the `120k` value, Is there any option to fix this axis rendering behavior?

```
var s1 = ["84486", "74987", "120249"];
var ticks = ['Length', 'Width', 'Height'];

$.jqplot('revi_chart', [s1], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'w'},
        rendererOptions: { barDirection: 'horizontal'},
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: { tickOptions: { showLabel: true, showGridline: false}},
        yaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, ticks: ticks,
        tickOptions: { showGridline: false }}
    },
    highlighter: { show: false}
});
```

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/frelis/x7Lyj5t6/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make s1 an array of numbers. It expects numbers on the X axis.
Change the code from:

```
var s1 = ["84486", "74987", "120249"];
```

to

```
var s1 = [84486, 74987, 120249];
```

see the working version at: http://jsfiddle.net/x7Lyj5t6/13/

This way X axis will always be automatically setting the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max value on the XAxis like that :

```
axes: {
        xaxis: { tickOptions: { showLabel: true, showGridline: false},
     max:200000},
        yaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, ticks: ticks,
            tickOptions: { showGridline: false }}
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/dox289ea/

You can get the max value of your array and set the max axis value like this too :

```
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(null, s1);

xaxis: { tickOptions: { showLabel: true, showGridline: false},
         max: maxVal +10000},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/7ntw19Lp/

Have a good day !